# Simulteneous demultiplexer, multiple relay switch?

Tags: relay, logic-gates, switching

I'm lacking proper terminology here: I have 3 inputs and I would like to route their signals into 3 different pins (on a microcontroller).

But I want to be able to *re-route* the pins (without physically switching cables).

For example:

```
              -------
           1 |       |
A  ---->   2 |       |
B  ---->   3 |       |
C  ---->   4 |       |
```

Then, programmatically switch to this configuration:

```
              -------
        /->1 |       |
A  ----/   2 |       |
B  ---->   3 |       |
C  ---->   4 |       |
```

So it's like a set of switches, but very complicated (select k out of n; many possible combinations)

I looked at demultiplexers and they don't do it. I think this must be a frequent (or at least: solved) problem. Is there an IC that could relay the signals as I want?

Edit (to provide more context):

My device has one USB port for a sensor. I want to use different types of sensors (they use different interfaces/protocols: IC2, SPI, PWM ...). The microcontroller has certain pins dedicated to IC2/PWM (and it is not always possible to overwrite them). The physical connection (USB cable) is also fixed. Therefore I'd like to 'rewire' the signal routes programatically.

Comment: Just connect them to the other pins as well as the main pins?

Comment: do you mean like an analog switch? 4051, 4052?

Comment: A micro can deal with this "programatically" so what's the problem here?

Comment: Agreed. Please give some context and explain the real problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @WesleyLee - unless I'm reading the datasheet wrongly, this won't help. There is only one communication port and the 4051 cycles through the pins. What I need is to have 'simple' bridge between selected pins.

Comment: @Andyaka - do you mean I should lead all 3 inputs to all 8 microcontroller pins? That's 24 connections. I feel like there could be a better solution.

Comment: It seems what I need is called "Switch matrix"; inputs can be independently routed to variable output

https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/FM/FMS6502.pdf

But it is also expensive component and too sophisticated for my usecase, if you know better solution, please share!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My device has one USB port for a sensor. I want to use different types of sensors (they use different interfaces/protocols: IC2, SPI, PWM ...).

Do you mean "one USB connector"? Using a USB connector for anything other than USB seems a bad idea.

If you must use one connector for multiple applications I would agree with Andy aka that you should wire each pin to multiple I/Os. Feeding multiple inputs should be fine and the unwanted outputs can be tri-stated to disconnect them.

Answer (score 1):

To extend Transistor's answer:

I was looking for a "switch matrix" or "crossbar switch". However, these IC's are either too expensive or too limited (dual channel). A very powerful solution is a MCU as a switch matrix

http://www.nxp.com/products/microcontrollers-and-processors/arm-processors/lpc-cortex-m-mcus/lpc-cortex-m0-plus-m0/lpc800-low-cost-cortex-m0-plus:MC_71785

"8.9 Switch Matrix (SWM)
The switch matrix controls the function of each digital or mixed analog/digital pin in a
highly flexible way by allowing to connect many functions like the USART, SPI, SCT, and
I2C functions to any pin that is not power or ground. "

It is a MCU so it has to be programmed, however it can be controlled using IO pins (to switch to different configurations).

Answer (score 0):

If you actually need full combinatoric control, three 4-output demultiplexers would work, one for each input pin. Just make sure that they are tri-state (read: high-impedance on deselected outputs), and make sure that whatever is driving them doesn't drive multiple demuxes to conflict on the same output.

This would consume 6 IO pins, though, which may be excessive. There are various ways to cut this down if necessary, but they add complexity.

Otherwise, just grab a few tri-state buffers and switch them on and off as necessary.